# Cannot read property addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have 2 separate files. A `html` and a `js` file. I get the following error:

> (index):118 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

**Resources**

---

**html**

```
<form><input id="product1" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="12" />
<input id="product1" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="13" />
<input id="product1" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="14" />
<button type="submit">Subscribe</button></form>
```

**JS**

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
    .map(item => item.value)
    .join(',');

  console.log(`test.com/addtocart?${values}`);
});
```

Comment: it seems to work correctly  , see the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dfr0mg62/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your HTML is not loaded when the JS is executing already. Include your javascript **after** your HTML and it will work (before `</body>`)